# Magento: Expandable navigation on category pages?

Tags: magento

I am looking for an extension that can make the navigation in the sitebar expandable, like here: http://www.21run.com/ru_de/herren.html

I searched and came up with http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sidebar-navigation-menu-professional.html but I think it is not supporting what I want.

Does anybody know of an extension that does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following free layered navigation extension

http://www.manadev.com/advanced-layered-navigation-ce

It allows multiselect in filter.

You can check demo there.